# Adding Elements Clears Textareas

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've run into an issue with my JavaScript web app, which may be a bug in the browser itself, but my searching has brought no results at all on what may be happening...

Whenever the icon is added to the desktop, ALL inputs and textareas on the page are cleared and ALL scrolling on the page is also reset to the top...

The app is designed to mimic a desktop environment, and I've hit a snag on adding custom desktop icons. Each desktop icon is a `div` on the main desktop `div`.

Here's the code for adding the desktop icons... (some parts of it were removed because they are irrelevant to the question)

```
document.getElementById('desktop').innerHTML +=
    '<div class="app" ...styling and onclicks in here...>' +
    '<div class="appIcon" ...><img ...></div>' +
    '<div class="appDesc" ...>' + appname + '</div>' +
    '</div>';
```

I add HTML elements the exact same way in many hundreds of other places in the app, and this never happened once.

---

For those who wish to do some investigation, here's the app itself: https://aaron-os-mineandcraft12.c9.io/

Right-click the 'desktop', and select "Add Icon". Enter any name in the name field, any integer in the ID field, and the path of some app (for example, you can use `apps.settings`) in the path field.

If the same issue carries over to your browser, all textareas on the page will be cleared when you go to click "Create Icon".

---

You can also see the code itself for adding desktop icons within the app...

Click the desktop icon called 'Files', and navigate to `apps.iconMaker.vars` (currently #7 in the list)

The function in question is called `buildIcon`. Just click on it and it will open in the aOS text editor, and you can see the actual source code for it.

For clarification, here's exactly what I'm looking for.

> Why is adding the element to the 'desktop' causing the entire page to reset all scrolling and textareas, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: kinda sounds like the page is doing a postback.  I was not able to see the issue because of error... aOS Fatal Error - Script Paused. Error in https://aaron-os-mineandcraft12.c9.io/script.js Module 'idle' at [1]: SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script  Send error report?

Comment: Wow, I've never seen that error generated before... Looks like it was an anonymous function though... What browser are you using?

Comment: Just did some research on postback, doesnt sound like thats it... No `form` element and the Create button is not a submit type and has no POST function... Even the process that saves the icon asks for a different page with XMLHttpRequest... Ive never had trouble with the saving function before either...

Comment: I got them in IE 11 Firefox and chrome

Comment: That's strange... I found the error reports (or at least, I found the reports for FF and Chrome)... Chrome had an Unexpected Identifier, and FF had the end of script thing... What did you do that caused the error? The line numbers are 1, it looks like the errors took place in an anonymous function... I can't replicate it...